# okhttp3 error when upload file over 500Mb

Tags: android, okhttp

I get an error when a large file is uploaded :
**okhttp3.internal.http2.StreamResetException: stream was reset: STREAM_CLOSED**
How should I solve this problem ?

Comment: Check if the server allows upload of such huge files.

Comment: i checked. and postman uploaded 1Gb file.